# Data is not saved in the Database

Tags: android

I have created a database with the android when i add some data in it and i try to see the contents i have added it is empty
this the class of the database

```
package tt.aa.xx;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Dbinfo {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_ID";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="person_name";
    public static final String KEY_SCALERATING="person_rate";
    public static final String KEY_AGE="person_age";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="SignDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private Dbhelper ourHelper;
    public final Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    private static class Dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public Dbhelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+KEY_AGE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+KEY_SCALERATING+" TEXT NOT NULL);");         
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIESTS"+DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }


    }
    public Dbinfo(Context c)
    {
        ourcontext=c;
    }
    public Dbinfo open()throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper=new Dbhelper(ourcontext);
        ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }
    public long create(String nameS, String ratingScaleS,String ageS) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,nameS);
    cv.put(KEY_SCALERATING, ratingScaleS);
    cv.put(KEY_AGE, ageS);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
    }
    public String getdata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String []columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_AGE,KEY_SCALERATING};
        String result="";
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iage=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
        int iScale=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALERATING);
        for(c.moveToFirst();c.moveToLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result=result+c.getString(iRow)+c.getString(iName)+c.getString(iage)+c.getString(iScale)+'\n';
        }

        return result;

    }


}
```

And this the class of the activity of the xml

```
package tt.aa.xx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText Name,RatingScale,age;
    Button Update_sqlDB,view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        intialze();
    }
    private void intialze() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.NameED);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageET);
        RatingScale=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratingscaleET);
        Update_sqlDB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.updateSQLDB_BT);
        view=(Button)findViewById(R.id.viewBT);
        Update_sqlDB.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.updateSQLDB_BT:
            Toast.makeText(this, "hsh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean diditwork=true;
            try
            {String NameS=Name.getText().toString();
            String RatingScaleS=RatingScale.getText().toString();
            String ageS=age.getText().toString();
            Dbinfo info=new Dbinfo(this);
            info.open();
            info.create(NameS,RatingScaleS,ageS);
            info.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                String error=e.toString();
                Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error");
                TextView tt=new TextView(this);
                tt.setText("Erro in saving");
                d.setContentView(tt);
                d.show();                       
            }
            finally
            {
                if(diditwork)
                {
                    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("OHH YEAAH");
                    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("sucess");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(age.getWindowToken(),0);
            break;
        case R.id.viewBT:
            Intent i=new Intent("tt.aa.xx.VIEWDB");
            startActivity(i);

            break;

        }
    }
}
```

And i create a final Activity to see the contents of the Database

```
package tt.aa.xx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewDb extends Activity {

    TextView sqlinfo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
        sqlinfo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SQLinfoTV);
        Dbinfo infos=new Dbinfo(this);
        infos.open();
        String data=infos.getdata();
        sqlinfo.setText(data);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read it carefully and your Database helper DbInfo looks Ok.

I think the Problem is to be found in your getData() method.

```
    for(c.moveToFirst();c.moveToLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result=result+c.getString(iRow)+c.getString(iName)+c.getString(iage)+c.getString(iScale)+'\n';
    }
```

Here you use as the condition of the for loop cursor.moveToLast() which returns true when it sucessfully moved the cursor to the last entry.

replace c.moveToLast with !c.isAfterLast(). If there is no other error you should get results.

Answer (score 0):

In dealing with database you have to care about your creation.

```
1.Check database is created or not?
2.Check table is created or not?
3.if first and second correct then you have to takecare about CRUD operation.
```

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) is helpful for you and most effective demo.